# How can I include an image that cannot be changed in my application?

Tags: .net, winforms

I have used many images in my application with the resource file.

The question is here that other users of my app, can they change my bitmaps to their own bitmaps by replacing and renaming them?!

For example My Logo with 250x120 dimension will appeared on splash screen.

Is it necessary to put `logo.png` near my exe file?

if yes, can users replace a another file as name as `logo.png` near to my exe file for showing their own file?

What is the way to avoid this bad thing?

Comment: probably ok if they are placed not closer than 42 centimeters apart ;-)

Comment: are you kidding ? iam serious about that. I will be glad if you help me.

Comment: They need to do way instain mother.

Comment: @Parkhid, sorry but the question was very vague, have no clue what you ment with "near". Please rephrase your question

Comment: sorry ,  by near  I mean : same directory of the exe file

Comment: I was wondering why this was off-topic. Then I saw the title before edit. Oh well, no need for new answers anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should keep any graphics in a resource file, not as separate files w/ your application.

[This link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vbgeneral/thread/14e60d7c-85fe-49c1-9057-e132abd5f71e) may help.

Per the response there:

> There are many ways to do this
>
> 1. Imagelist control : Add your icons/images to imagelist and you can access them at runtime
> 2. Managed Resources : Right click your project name, and select properties from menu, on properties, select resources tab and add your images or icons as existing item.Now you can access the icon or image from resources as
>    Dim img as Bitmap = My.Resources.YourResourcesNameWithoutExtension
>    Dim Ic as Icon = My.Resources.YourResourcesNameWithoutExtension
> 3. Embedded Resources : To add any file as an embedded resource in a windows forms application, add the file to the project with Project | Add Existing Item or right click your project name in solution explorer and click Add Existing item. Then select the file in the Solution Explorer, go to the Properties Window, and set its Build Action property to Embedded Resource. The file will be embedded within your compiled executable, when you build the project.

Comment: so they cannot change them yes ? and without a resource editor ?

Comment: Correct, it's compiled with your exe.  See the link above.

Comment: That doesn't mean they can't be changed, it's just some more steps...

Answer (score 3):

If the file has been compiled into a resource, it will be embedded in your executable. Someone else placing a file of the same name near your executable will not have any effect, because it has already been compiled.

A hacker can still edit the resource within your executable if they're really intent on replacing your logo, but it won't happen accidentally.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call it "hacking" to simply replace an obvious file.  Anyway, you can do it several ways, but the hardest to change is an embedded resource.  See #3 on this site: http://www.progware.org/Blog/post/Image-Resources-in-WinForms-and-WPF.aspx.  Note that you are currently doing #2.

Comment: You can certainly make things harder than an embedded resource - but anything beyond that point is just getting into an arms race with the hacker, for little gain (who cares if they replace a bitmap?)

Comment: @bdonlan: Yeah, I should have clarified it's not THE hardest.  It's the hardest out of the standard ways of including an image in an application.  You can add encryption, assembly signing, obfuscation, etc., but there is little point.